# Publish class fields as another class field

Tags: c#, nested, field

```
public class Foo
{
Bar Field{get;set;}
}

    public class Bar
    {
    public int Value{get;set};
    public int Value2{get;set;}
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like that in C# :

```
Foo a = new Foo();
a.Value  = 5;
a.Value2 = 8;
```

In the other words, is there possibility to publish fields of Bar class as if Bar was a Base Class?

Comment: You want composition to work like inheritance? You have to roll your own properties in Foo.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `Bar` type property in your class `Foo`, you have composition. You can access the Fields through that property like:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
a.Field.Value = 1;
a.Field.Value2 = 2;
```

But you have to modify your current code like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Field { get; set; } //make the property public
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

The other option is to inherit `Bar` in `Foo` like:

```
public class Foo : Bar
{
    public int FooID { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can access `Bar`'s field directly like:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
a.Value = 1;
a.Value2 = 2;
```

Comment: Or `public Bar Field { get; private set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can add properties to the "outer" class to expose them explicitely.

```
public class Foo
{
    Bar Field{get;set;}

    public int Value{get { return Field.Value;} }
    public int Value2{get { return Field.Value2;} }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Value{get;set};
    public int Value2{get;set;}
}
```

However, this of course is not very handy. If you really want to have something like this more "automatically", you probalby could do it with `dynamic` and custom TypeDescriptors, but that in turn will prevent compile-time type and member verification.. I don't recommend that until you absolutelyhave to.

Comment: OP uses `set` accessor as well

Comment: I believe in his intelligence to find that pattern and apply accordingly.

Comment: That's what I want to achieve, but I want to have it automatically

Comment: It is not possible. Only inheritance allows this. As I've said, you can partially have something-like-this with `dynamic` and/or intelligent proxies and/or DLR runtime, but this has very far consequences that you'd not expect from "just exposing a property of my sub-object". You have to revise what you want to achieve. Composition is not inheritance.

Comment: Ah, and one more thing: you can actually have it as explicit properties in the 'outer object' like I've shown, and have it written automatically. Please see the 'T4 code templates'. The IDE/Compiler can scan the classes' definitions and can generate all the forwarding code. It will still be an ugly explicit forwards, but you will not have to write that. (well, except for the T4 which you will have to write or find on the internet;) )